# Find a relative path in sitemap

Tags: scala, lift

I have defined some menus in sitemap:

```
...
Menu("index",S ? "home") / "index"
...
```

Now, in runtime, I want to determine the relatative url from name of the menu. So I would like if some function like this existed: `LiftRules.siteMap.getUrl("index")` and the result would be a `String` : `/contextPath/index`. I ignore the fact that `sitemap` returns a `Box`. Is there some function like this? Btw I want to use it in `S.redirect`, it accepts a `String`, If I hardcode some String there, It can create problems if I later change the path in `Menu` definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a link method in Loc:

```
val details = Loc("details", "profile" :: "details" :: Nil, "Details", Hidden)
details.link.createPath
```